# Does anyone use BetterAuthorizationSample?

Tags: c, macos, launchd, setuid

On OS X privileged operations are done through AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() around which Apple published two recommendations:

The old MoreAuth using setuid helper tools.

The current BetterAuthorizationSample littering the system with launchd files.

I don't know any applications using the latter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used it, and it's a pain to implement. FWIW, I know that BBEdit and PGP Desktop use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to use it at the moment. The only objection I have is that when one deletes my application the helper tool stays where it is.